# How to do as guide "Re-run Spring Boot Configuration Annotation Processor to update generated metadata"?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea

For example, I have file `DataSourceConfig.java`

```java
package com.apress.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "jdbc")
public class DataSourceConfig {
    private String driver;
    private String url;
    private String username;
    private String password;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "DataSourceConfig [driver=" + driver + ", url=" + url + ", username=" + username + "]";
    }

    public String getDriver() {
        return driver;
    }

    public void setDriver(String driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

}
```

How to do this notice?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just a reminder that configuration properties will not be available until you Make changes and annotation processor is re-run

You can enable annotation processors in IntelliJ via the following:

- Click on File
- Click on Settings
- In the little search box in the upper-left hand corner, search for "Annotation Processors"
- Check "Enable annotation processing"
- Click <kbd>OK</kbd>

[image]
or
add dependency in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

[Configuring the Annotation Processor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/3.0.0/reference/html/configuration-metadata.html#appendix.configuration-metadata.annotation-processor)
and add anatation `@Configuration`